# Creating a custom icon in canvas HTML 5

Tags: html5-canvas

I'm just new to canvas and I'm trying to draw a custom shape. I just don't know if this one is possible?

[custom icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnThB.png)

I have a snippet below and I'm having problems with the seventh canvas. Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

```js
  //player
  var c = document.getElementById('test1');
  /* c.height = 83;
   c.width = 83;*/
  var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
  var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
  var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);

  c.width = width;
  c.height = height;
  var cx = c.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = c.width / 2;
  var centerY = c.height / 2;
  var radius = c.height * .35;
  // define the arc path
  cx.beginPath();
  cx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  cx.fillStyle = 'rgba(250,0,0,1)';
  cx.fill();
  cx.closePath()
    //end of player

  //banker
  var c = document.getElementById('test2');
  var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
  var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
  var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
  c.width = width;
  c.height = height;
  var cx = c.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = c.width / 2;
  var centerY = c.height / 2;
  var radius = c.height * .35;
  // define the arc path
  cx.beginPath();
  cx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  cx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,250,1)';
  cx.fill();
  cx.closePath()
    //end of banker 

  //tie
  var c = document.getElementById('test3');
  var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
  var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
  var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
  c.width = width;
  c.height = height;
  var cx = c.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = c.width / 2;
  var centerY = c.height / 2;
  var radius = c.height * .35;
  // define the arc path
  cx.beginPath();
  cx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  cx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,250,0,1)';
  cx.fill();
  cx.closePath()

  //red ring
  var c = document.getElementById('test3');
  var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
  var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
  var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
  c.width = width;
  c.height = height;
  var cx = c.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = c.width / 2;
  var centerY = c.height / 2;
  var radius = c.height * .30;
  // define the arc path
  cx.beginPath();
  cx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  cx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(250,0,0,1)';
  cx.lineWidth = c.width * .12;
  cx.stroke();
  cx.closePath()

  //blue ring
  var c = document.getElementById('test4');
  var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
  var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
  var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
  c.width = width;
  c.height = height;
  var cx = c.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = c.width / 2;
  var centerY = c.height / 2;
  var radius = c.height * .30;
  // define the arc path
  cx.beginPath();
  cx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  cx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,250,1)';
  cx.lineWidth = c.width * .12;
  cx.stroke();
  cx.closePath()
    //end blue-ring


  //tie line
  var c = document.getElementById('test5');
  var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
  var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
  var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
  c.width = width;
  c.height = height;
  var cx = c.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = c.width / 2;
  var centerY = c.height / 2;
  var radius = c.height * .30;
  // define the line path

  // define the line path
  cx.beginPath()
  cx.moveTo(c.width * .714, c.height * .285);
  cx.lineTo(c.width * .285, c.height * .714);
  cx.lineWidth = c.width * .12;
  cx.lineCap = "round";
  cx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,250,0,1)';
  cx.stroke();
  cx.closePath();
  //end tie-line


  //player-tie
  var c = document.getElementById('test6');
  var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
  var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
  var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
  c.width = width;
  c.height = height;
  var cx = c.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = c.width / 2;
  var centerY = c.height / 2;
  var radius = c.height * .30;
  // define the line path

  // define the line path
  cx.beginPath()
  cx.moveTo(c.width * .714, c.height * .285);
  cx.lineTo(c.width * .285, c.height * .714);
  cx.lineWidth = c.width * .12;
  cx.lineCap = "round";
  cx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,250,0,1)';
  cx.stroke();
  cx.closePath();

  // define the arc path
  cx.beginPath();
  cx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  cx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,250,1)';
  cx.lineWidth = c.width * .12;
  cx.stroke();
  cx.closePath()
    //end player-tie

  //player-banker-pair
  var c = document.getElementById('test7');
  var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
  var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
  var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);

  c.width = width;
  c.height = height;
  var cx = c.getContext('2d');
  var centerX = c.width / 2;
  var centerY = c.height / 2;
  var radius = c.height * .35;
  // define the arc path
  cx.beginPath();
  cx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  cx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,250,1)';
  cx.fill();
  cx.closePath()

  //pair invisible circle
  radius = c.height * .12;
  // define the arc path
  cx.beginPath();
  cx.arc(c.width * .275, c.height * .275, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  cx.fillStyle = 'rgba(250,0,0,0)';
  cx.fill();
  cx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
  cx.closePath()

  //pair circle
  // define the arc path
  radius = c.height * .10;
  cx.beginPath();
  cx.arc(c.width * .275, c.height * .275, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
  cx.fillStyle = 'rgba(250,0,0,1)';
  /*cx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"; */
  cx.fill();
  cx.closePath()



  //end player-banker-pair
```

```css
 canvas {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 }
```

```html
<canvas id="test1"></canvas>
<canvas id="test2"></canvas>
<canvas id="test3"></canvas>
<canvas id="test4"></canvas>
<canvas id="test5"></canvas>
<canvas id="test6"></canvas>
<canvas id="test7"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how this could be accomplished ...

```js
//player
var c = document.getElementById('test1');
/* c.height = 83;
 c.width = 83;*/
var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);

c.width = width;
c.height = height;
var cx = c.getContext('2d');
var centerX = c.width / 2;
var centerY = c.height / 2;
var radius = c.height * .35;
// define the arc path
cx.beginPath();
cx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
cx.fillStyle = 'rgba(250,0,0,1)';
cx.fill();

//end of player

//banker
var c = document.getElementById('test2');
var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
c.width = width;
c.height = height;
var cx = c.getContext('2d');
var centerX = c.width / 2;
var centerY = c.height / 2;
var radius = c.height * .35;
// define the arc path
cx.beginPath();
cx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
cx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,250,1)';
cx.fill();

//end of banker 

//tie
var c = document.getElementById('test3');
var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
c.width = width;
c.height = height;
var cx = c.getContext('2d');
var centerX = c.width / 2;
var centerY = c.height / 2;
var radius = c.height * .35;
// define the arc path
cx.beginPath();
cx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
cx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,250,0,1)';
cx.fill();


//red ring
var c = document.getElementById('test3');
var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
c.width = width;
c.height = height;
var cx = c.getContext('2d');
var centerX = c.width / 2;
var centerY = c.height / 2;
var radius = c.height * .30;
// define the arc path
cx.beginPath();
cx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
cx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(250,0,0,1)';
cx.lineWidth = c.width * .12;
cx.stroke();


//blue ring
var c = document.getElementById('test4');
var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
c.width = width;
c.height = height;
var cx = c.getContext('2d');
var centerX = c.width / 2;
var centerY = c.height / 2;
var radius = c.height * .30;
// define the arc path
cx.beginPath();
cx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
cx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,250,1)';
cx.lineWidth = c.width * .12;
cx.stroke();

//end blue-ring


//tie line
var c = document.getElementById('test5');
var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
c.width = width;
c.height = height;
var cx = c.getContext('2d');
var centerX = c.width / 2;
var centerY = c.height / 2;
var radius = c.height * .30;
// define the line path

// define the line path
cx.beginPath()
cx.moveTo(c.width * .714, c.height * .285);
cx.lineTo(c.width * .285, c.height * .714);
cx.lineWidth = c.width * .12;
cx.lineCap = "round";
cx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,250,0,1)';
cx.stroke();

//end tie-line


//player-tie
var c = document.getElementById('test6');
var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);
c.width = width;
c.height = height;
var cx = c.getContext('2d');
var centerX = c.width / 2;
var centerY = c.height / 2;
var radius = c.height * .30;
// define the line path

// define the line path
cx.beginPath()
cx.moveTo(c.width * .714, c.height * .285);
cx.lineTo(c.width * .285, c.height * .714);
cx.lineWidth = c.width * .12;
cx.lineCap = "round";
cx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,250,0,1)';
cx.stroke();


// define the arc path
cx.beginPath();
cx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
cx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,0,250,1)';
cx.lineWidth = c.width * .12;
cx.stroke();

//end player-tie

//player-banker-pair
var c = document.getElementById('test7');
var cs = getComputedStyle(c);
var width = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('width'), 10);
var height = parseInt(cs.getPropertyValue('height'), 10);

c.width = width;
c.height = height;
var cx = c.getContext('2d');
var centerX = c.width / 2;
var centerY = c.height / 2;
var radius = c.height * .35;
// define the arc path
cx.beginPath();
cx.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
cx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0,0,250,1)';
cx.fill();


//pair invisible circle
radius = c.height * .12;
// define the arc path
cx.beginPath();
cx.arc(c.width * .275, c.height * .275, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
cx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out"; //switched position
cx.fillStyle = 'rgba(250,0,0,1)'; //modified
cx.fill();



//pair circle
// define the arc path
radius = c.height * .10;
cx.beginPath();
cx.arc(c.width * .275, c.height * .275, radius - 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
cx.fillStyle = 'rgba(250,0,0,1)';
cx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"; //added
cx.fill();
```

```css
canvas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="test1"></canvas>
<canvas id="test2"></canvas>
<canvas id="test3"></canvas>
<canvas id="test4"></canvas>
<canvas id="test5"></canvas>
<canvas id="test6"></canvas>
<canvas id="test7"></canvas>
```

<sup>*apology for not giving any explanation*</sup>